# Gradle custom task with java code

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Gradle, and I need to make some preprocessing on compilation phase. My preprocessor is a class from an external library (a dependency, loaded from Maven Central). How can I wrote such `task`?

I have code like:

```
  buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
                classpath group: 'com.googlecode.htmlcompressor', name: 'htmlcompressor', version: '1.4'
            }
        }
        task compressXML {
                    logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.INFO
                    String xml = file('assets/menu.xml').text; 
                    XmlCompressor compressor = new XmlCompressor();
                    String compressedXml = compressor.compress(xml);
                    println compressedXml;
                }
```

but the problem that Gradle don't see `XmlCompressor` class:

```
build.gradle': 70: unable to resolve class XmlCompressor 
   @ line 70, column 27.
                 XmlCompressor compressor = new XmlCompressor();
                               ^

  build file '../build.gradle': 70: unable to resolve class XmlCompressor 
   @ line 70, column 40.
                 XmlCompressor compressor = new XmlCompressor();
                                            ^

  2 errors
```

Comment: You will have to import the class like in any other regular Java class.

Answer (score 0):

if you use [JCP preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor) then you can visit its page and there is [wiki page how to make preprocessing with gradle for android projects](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor/wiki/AndroidGradlePreprocessing)