# Custom Android lint rule that takes input from outside

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I need to write a rule to find if a specific String is found in the comment. I'm referencing to [this class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/CommentDetector.java) to do the comment check, but in this class they only check for a predefined String (STOPSHIP). Now is there any way that the Detector class can refer to a value outside of it? Either a file contains a String or a config file that belongs to an Android project would be great.

Comment: Hack? Use multiple lint rules for your strings inside of multiple AAR or modules and toggle them in your gradle file. Ref: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules

Comment: @MorrisonChang The string can be anything, so we cannot predetermine it.

Comment: You might want to explain how "any string" can they be lint rules as part of the build process. Alternatively add in your own [preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30151456/295004) or [custom gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44555392/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I mean the user can define an arbitrary string and have the lint performed the check to find if that string exists in the code.